# Science fiction short story about underground society where children are kept away from parents

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, underground-civilization

I'm looking for a science fiction short story about an alien society that lives underground, and there is a widespread sense of detachment from one's offspring, and children being raised isolated from their parents and never having contact with them. I remember the protagonist (probable a "female") being an outlier, wanting to be a part of her child's life, which was frowned upon by her friends. For some reason I don't remember a physical description of these beings, nor do I remember any "male" character being in it.

The next part I'm not even sure its from the same story because I don't quite remember how one part connects to the other. If it's not the same story it was probably in the same book or by the same author.

Somehow someone's mind (maybe the child's?) gets transported far away (maybe to another planet, or the same planet's surface). The mind is described falling from earth atmosphere, and landing inside a plane, then wondering around (maybe from one passenger to another) and finally "landing" inside a baby. I remember a description of the senses being overwhelming, and the baby starts crying. This I think was the ending of the story.

For some context I remember reading this very young when I was just getting into sci fi, and I started reading the classics so it was probably Asimov, Clark, Bradbury or something like that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately what year did you read this?  Would it have been in a magazine or an anthology?

Comment: I must have read it 15 to 20 years ago, probably in an antology. But the short story itself is probably much older, since I remember I was reading mostly "old" sci fi back then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is [The Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deep_(short_story)) by Isaac Asimov.

The Deep describes a society where knowing familial relationships is abhorrent - but one of the characters is aware that she's the mother of another. Even though she feels shame and won't reveal the knowledge to anyone else, she takes pride when her offspring is chosen for an important mission.

They live in the heart of a planet, close to the warm core, but are running out of energy. She remembers when they closed off one of the outer caverns in order to save power; due to population loss, everyone was accommodated in warmer caverns closer to the core.

> The offspring's mission is to find a new place to live. They're going to try and "send" the offspring to another planet, telepathically. The one attempt will use more than half of their total remaining energy reserves; failure is not an option. To his horror, he finds himself in the mind of a baby aboard a plane, unable to directly trigger the cube-like device that's been sent with him.

It was anthologized in [The Martian Way and Other Stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Way_and_Other_Stories).

Comment: Yes! That’s the one! You are my hero, man. Thank you!